# Git - Where can I find some drills on how to do just slightly complex things with Git?

Tags: git

I want to learn how to do more complex operations using Git. Currently I use GitHub and I can:

1. clone a repository
2. init a new repository
3. add and remove files from a repository
4. make commits
5. push commits

Whenever things get even slightly more complex, I find myself quickly feeling out of my depth.

Reading tutorials and books do not provide as much help as actually experimenting. Does any one know of a website where I can run drills of the more complex maneuvers in Git, such as merges and rolling back changes and using multiple branches and so forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using GitHub, have a look at https://github.com/grayghostvisuals/Practice-Git. It links to a half-dozen learning resources, and is intended just for playing around as you describe.

The [challenges](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1) section seems to be exactly the type of guided-exercises you wanted, although it is browser-based.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources for learning git include:

- [Official Github tutorial](http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html)
- [Github challenges](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1)
- [Github tips and tricks by git ready](http://gitready.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow.com.. no, this is not a joke. I would go through the questions here by vote count.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pro Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book) is a *just right* paced introduction to git.  It walks, command by command, thru nearly every aspect of git used on a daily basis.  There are plenty of diagrams to go along with the commands.  As such it is a great book to follow along with in a repository of your own.

The only downside is you will have to create the repository and get it to the shape the book starts at, but the early instructions prepare you for the later ones.

There are lots of sites and blogs that describe individual actions, with the steps needed to take them.  There are also many answers to questions on Stack Overflow that give step by step instructions.

The best way to make sure to not just read the steps; build a small repository and follow along.  You will become proficient in no time.